# "Unknown scripting language VBScript" IIS 7.5 + 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, vbscript, asp-classic

Migrated an old classic ASP application from Server 2008 R2 to a new Server 2008 R2 SP1 and having serious issues now.  All set ups and configs are identical between the "old" and new servers, no code has changed, all I did was move it from one box to another.

Initially 500s will start appearing with a `Server.CreateObject Failed` on `CDO.Message` eventually turning into :

```
Unknown scripting language

/path/file.asp, line 1

The scripting language 'VBScript' is not found on the server.
```

There are other classic ASP sites working fine on the same server (in fact, the site this application is a part of is also classic ASP and works fine).

Simply recycling the app pool gets rid of all errors and the application works for an undetermined amount of requests.  This makes me feel it is not a permissions or necessarily a config error.  At the moment, as it's internally used, I have the application pool recycling every 30 minutes, but it still dies multiple times a day and we are not talking 000's of requests here, a few dozen at most.

I have duplicated the setup on another 2008 R2 SP1 box and have the same results, if it could have any bearing, these are Rackspace Cloud Servers; old ones are in the US new ones are in the UK.

I am happy to accept "coding error" as a solution, if you can give me some hints where to look and why it was fine on 2003 and 2008 R2.

My biggest concern is that these servers are supposed to be taking our entire collection of sites running happily on the US servers, some of which are also old and classic ASP, so will they all fail as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just exploring possible causes, you may want to check if your old server was Windows 32 bits. If it was, your new scenario could be forcing a COM object to be used as an "out of process" instance, which may have [performance side effects](http://axcs.blogspot.com/2006/07/asp-tips-tip-7-out-of-process.html).

Comment: Both servers 64-bit, only difference as far as I can tell is SP1.  Both servers are still running, as haven't migrated all the old sites over yet for fear of further issues.